# What comes after learning objective-c for programming an ios device?

Tags: objective-c, ios

It appears the language is the same for either device ios or mac os on a mbp, but if I learn Objective-C in a tutorial, won't I also need to learn cocoa or cocoa touch to program effectively?

I'm not sure how to start on my path of learning to program an ios device.  I know I need to learn objective-c and that appears to work on all apple products.  Then do I move to cocoa touch for ipad and iphone?  What comes after objective-c?

The type of project is akin to a web app but native objective-c app instead.  Have ui, buttons, the app hits some back end location, returns data, I put it on that same ui.  Only, as stated, use objective-c and whatever framework and library to do it (that's my dilemma.  I dont know what to do next after objective-c).

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa and Objective-c go hand in hand. For getting started, I would suggest going over some old WWDC footage and following some of the examples there.

As far as Cocoa and Cocoa touch are concerned, they are very similar in many aspects, same name conventions, similar structure, etc. Learn one, and you can easily pick up the other.

@craig adds:

I would further this answer by also mentioning that Objective-C is a programming language, while Cocoa/Cocoa Touch are collections of frameworks that are provided by Apple, and used by developers to add functionality to their programs. (Which are written in Objective-C.) The Cocoa frameworks contain various UI components like buttons, table views, sliders, etc. in addition to various fundamental classes like NSString and other text- and graphics-based APIs

Comment: I would further this answer by also mentioning that Objective-C is a *programming language*, while Cocoa/Cocoa Touch are collections of *frameworks* that are provided by Apple, and used by developers to add functionality to their programs. (Which are written in Objective-C.) The Cocoa frameworks contain various UI components like buttons, table views, sliders, etc. in addition to various fundamental classes like `NSString` and other text- and graphics-based APIs.

Comment: @craig I added that to the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I started my learning by watching thenewboston's xcode tutorials:
you can begin with this [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xqn5IHbusA)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer books for some strange reason and I found that the Apress [series](http://www.apress.com/9781430236054) of IOS development is really good.  The book goes through developing iPhone and iPad apps using all kinds of Cocoa libraries.  There's a lot of good books out there on the subject; I would go find one that looks like it would suit your needs.